# blazor application crash when debugging after windows march 14 2023 updates

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

My blazor app crashes at startup when debugging. If I start it without the debugger it works ok.  This happened on march 15 after .net 6.0.15 updates.

This is the trace:

> Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy[0] DevToolsProxy::Run: Exception System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index'))  ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.GetItem(Int32 index)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.get_Item(Object key)    at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoProxy.AcceptEvent(SessionId sessionId, String method, JObject args, CancellationToken token)    at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy.OnEvent(SessionId sessionId, String method, JObject args, CancellationToken token)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()    at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy.Run(Uri browserUri, WebSocket ideSocket)

Googled and no results found for this issue. Tried to update nuget packages to 6.0.15 and no results.

Comment: tried to do a clean rebuild the entire project? also, check what was the update item was. in the unlikely event it was a .net framework update, you might want to reverse the update.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66149

Comment: Yeah I have the exact same problem!

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be an issue with the recent Update, [see related discussion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189857/blazor-app-crashes-when-debugging-after-windows-se)

> A fix for me was to remove all breakpoints from code. From the Debug
> menu, choose Clear All Breakpoints (CTRL+SHIFT+F9)

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/set-and-clear-a-breakpoint)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Is there some github issue posted for this?

Comment: @Henkie85 I think this might be it: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83452

Answer (score 2):

Its fixed in the latest version of Edge..
Version 111.0.1661.44 (Official build) (64-bit)

Update your Edge installation to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad Chromium update. Firefox works. Waiting for next update or will downgrade.